Deleted posts get subtracted from review count in Staging Ground
After reaching 50/50 SG reviews:

I somehow dropped back down to 49/50:

It appears this happened when one of my reviewed SG posts got deleted. Abdul Aziz Barkat found this post that I voted off-topic which later got deleted as spam: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78581502
Later I noticed my SG review count decrementing again after another post that I voted off-topic got deleted by the OP: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78643890
This seems like a bug. The number of completed SG reviews shouldn't depend on deletion status.

At a guess - was something deleted? Check by using the filter - add all statuses and also "Your reviewed posts" in the Post attributes filter.

@VLAZ I don't see any indication of deletion in the filtered list like red background, "deleted" label, etc. It's possible that the SG UI doesn't mark deletions (yet), so later I can try to check them manually.

@tdy there's this SG post that you had reviewed which is now deleted.

Wait, I just realized "Show archived posts" has subcategories, and "Deleted" unchecked by default. That's why I didn't see it. Good catch @AbdulAzizBarkat

If it subtracts deleted posts, that seems like a clear bug; deletion shouldn't reduce this count, which is for # of questions reviewed, not # of published questions which are also still undeleted.

This should be fixed now. We updated the review count query to not exclude deleted posts. Let us know if you are still seeing issues.
